# Create SSH TUNNEL for DOCKER based applications to connect to database?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, devops

Iam trying to run a docker image from my mac terminal, my app contains a db connection to a aws rds instance which can be connected only through ssh.. usually i create a tunnel from remote host to 127.0.0.1. But when using docker this is not working..
How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Solved the problem with help of following article by christian emmer

https://emmer.dev/blog/tunneling-a-database-connection-with-docker-compose/